# How do I interact with a silverlight website from C++/C#

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight

i want to interact via code with a silverlight (ver. 4) website.
i need to scrape data from the silverlight object as well as click on buttons.

1. what would be the simple way to do this from c# ?
2. what would be the simple way to do this from c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "Silverlight Website".  Silverlight is a client-side technology.

Perhaps you could use something like Fiddler to examine the client to server conversation as the silverlight app is used.  You might then be able to emulate it in a C++ or C# application.

Otherwise you will need some scriptable UI testing tool perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can scrape any data from the Silverlight control directly.  If you "view source" on the page, that's all you will be able to get by scraping the page the control runs in.

UPDATE:

Anthony makes a good point that you might be able to observe the client/server communication.  Fiddler is a good tool to see what's happening in that communication.  If you find that the data you need is accessible in that communication, you could modify an http proxy to intercept the traffic and pull out the data you are interested in.  You would tell your web browser to go to your http proxy, and the http proxy would then connect to the internet (or your existing proxy if you use one).

There are numerous http proxies available with source code.  Here's a very simple one: http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=393

Comment: going over the data fields with the mouse pointer, the browser shows the data values in a small annotation box. i therefor assume that the data is accessible.

Comment: Try compiling the proxy from the link above and see if the proxy code observes the data values you need.  If so, it's a matter of picking them out of the information sent across the wire through the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

For what I gather from your very brief description of your problem I'm going to jump to the conclusion that you want to do basically what [Sliverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/SilverlightSpy) does. Checkout this blog post describing someone trying to emulate a little of what Spy does:

http://blog.aschommer.de/page/Injecting-code-into-Silverlight-applications.aspx

He's using Fiddler to modify the binaries in the XAP as they are downloaded, but before they're loaded by the SL plug-in. Pretty complicated.

Alternatively, I wonder if there something that could be done with a hosted browser in a C++/C# application, dynamic injection of javascript into the hosted page, [and the Javascript API that SL exposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903928%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).